# using c# Aforge library to make video streaming to android device

Tags: c#, android, video-streaming

my project is using C# ,the Aforge library, to make video streaming , which i will use this library to connect to my web cam and get the video ,then i will show this video on my android note 2 mobile  , is that possible? is there any tutorials for this project ?

note : I have succeed to connect with my webcam using Aforge , now i will go to the android side .